# Folder where Hive stores the exported CSV file

Tags: hadoop, hive, putty

I am using below command to export results of a query into a CSV file

```
hive -e 'YOUR QUERY HERE'  | sed 's/[\t]/,/g'  > sample.csv
```

Where does it store the csv file? I checked my comupter's user account folder but it is not there.

Comment: The directory where you executed the command from?

Comment: Its default. Is there a way to find it out by using command?

Comment: find . -name "sample.csv"